# MVC - What's causing break mode and exception when I save my .cshtml file while debugging?

Tags: razor, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-mvc-5, stack-overflow

I'm working in a medium sized MVC project. My typical workflow when I'm modifying a view is to start the debugger, edit the view, save the view and refresh the page in the browser. I think this is a pretty normal workflow.

Every dozen or so saves I will get an exception, the moment I hit save...

This strikes me as odd since the debugger is currently idle, I haven't yet refreshed the page so nothing has happened. We use hangfire and some other tasks that run on a schedule, but they never throw exceptions themselves.

It seems like I'm encountering a bug in Visual Studio. If it's not a bug I have no idea how to track it down. I'm using VS Enterprise 2015 Update 3 and MVC 5. I think I've had this problem for the past 6 months to a year. I can't narrow it down to a specific update, if it was even a new problem introduced by an update.

The exception window that opens doesn't have a "View Detail..." link and copy exception to clipboard only shows this:

```
System.StackOverflowException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in 
mscorlib.dll
```

To reiterate:

1. Run debugger
2. Open a view (.cshtml)
3. Make small change and Ctrl+S (repeate step 3 until exception thrown, usually less than 10 times)

[image]

Edit:
Even our simple breadcrumb view will eventually throw an SO Exception when I edit and save.

```
@using Api.Contracts.Net
@model IList<Crumb>

<div class="hrs-breadcrumbs">
    <ul>
        @foreach (var crumb in Model)
        {
            if (crumb.Id.HasValue && crumb.Id.Value != Guid.Empty)
            {
                <li>
                    @Html.ActionLink(crumb.Text, crumb.Action, crumb.Controller, new { Id = crumb.Id }, null)
                </li>
            }
            else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(crumb.Action) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(crumb.Controller))
            {
                <li>
                    @Html.ActionLink(crumb.Text, crumb.Action, crumb.Controller)
                </li>
            }
            else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(crumb.Action) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(crumb.Controller))
            {
                <li>
                    @Html.ActionLink(crumb.Text, crumb.Action)
                </li>
            }
            else
            {
                <li>
                    @crumb.Text
                </li>
            }

            <li class="separator">&gt;</li>
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide the code for your view?

Comment: I will see if I can find the simplest view that throws exception on save. It happens on every view I've edited so far we have 50-60 in our project. Not sure if the view code will help but we'll see!

Comment: @AnthonyForloney see edit, added code for a simple view that will throw after I save.

Comment: Try adding `<add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false" />` on web.config file, then install `KB3165756` patch. This is probably related to Intellisense leaks, see related details on https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/12317.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I was already on that update 3 patch. I added the browserlink key but it was no help. I can still reproduce break mode after saving. Thanks for the suggestion though!